Adding a local language that is not supported by Android
I have a working language switcher so that the user can change language.
The challange comes when I want to add Kissi, a local language spoken in Guinea. I have made the local code for this kq-rGN from official
When I run the app I can choose the language, but default English language is shown up.
If I look into the Translation Editor. It says null in the language tab and in the app, the language come up with kq and not English when it is English.
It actually worked on an old Android version, as old as 4, but on newer Android version, it doesn't work.
XML definition of array and code for setting language
<string-array name="language_codes">    
  <item>en-rUS</item>  
  <item>kq-rGN</item>
</string-array>
    
String lang = listCodeItems[position].substring(0, 2);
String country = listCodeItems[position].substring(listCodeItems[position].length() - 2);
LocaleHelper.setLocale(mContext, lang, country);
recreate();

Question how to get rare language to work?

"I have made the local code for this kq-rGN" -- that does not seem to be official. "how to get rare language to work?" -- you could not use string resources and do something else to handle multiple languages.

It is the language code, but not implemented into Android. link

That page shows a 3-letter language code of kqs, which is different than what you are using. However, as far as I know, Android does not support ISO 639 3-letter language codes. I do not see an official 2-letter language/region pair for Kissi. That is what I meant by "not official".

Yes, that is the really big challenge. There are more than 7000 languages and every 2-letter language code is taken. That's why I have to add the country code in my resources. So how to get around the Android limitations of language codes?

"So how to get around the Android limitations of language codes?" -- as I wrote, you could stop using string resources. For example, you can have your strings in JSON files that you read in and use. Your own language picker will tell you which strings to use from those files, based on the chosen language.
